# Opencart 3 Session data across the site

Tags: php, session-variables, opencart-3

I am just wondering that is it at all possible to set session across the Opencart website?

I mean I have created a subdirectory album on my Opencart website. What I want to achieve is on the product page when user clicks on the album icon it will be taken to the album subdirectory. On the album subdirectory, there will be a form, which the user will have to fill. After the user fills that form from the album directory on submit, user should redirect to that product page with the data of the form filled in the album directory. Also, the product page should have selected same options that he/she selected before clicking on the album.

I tried doing this by setting session data using following code on my album page.

`sessionStorage.setItem("album", JSON.stringify(tdata));`

And, then go back to the product page with `window.history.go(-1);`

But, I am still not being able to get the album session data on my product page. I tried both `$_SESSION` as well as `$this->session->data`

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created custom jquery file and injected it in my product page before `$data['heading_title'] = $product_info['name'];`.

```
$this->document->addScript('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/album.js');
```

In my album.js

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
      if (sessionStorage.getItem("album_data") != null) {
        var data = sessionStorage.getItem("album_data");
        console.log(data);
      }
}
```

In my custom album.php that is placed at mysite/album/

```
<script>
    sessionStorage.setItem("album_data", JSON.stringify(tdata));
    window.history.go(-1);
</script>
```

No need to create a session or anything. Creating a new session won't work in controller/product.php as OC has its own way of handling session data. So, we will not be able to access any $_SESSION data in it. OC only understands `$this-session->data`.

Answer (score 0):

In OC session data save:

```
$this->session->data['your_data'] = $some_data;
```

**Edited:**

To save and retrieve data in non OC site in the same domain use:
This file should be run before  to get that data. It's mean that data must to save to the session.
In your file where from you want to get data:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['my_data'] = $some_data;
```

To later retrieve the data from session where you want in the same domain, use the following code:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['my_data']))
    $sessionData = $_SESSION['my_data'];
else 
    $sessionData= '';
```

To clear the data, use the unset() PHP function, as follows:

```
unset($_SESSION['my_data']);
```

Comment: How can I access ```$this->session->data``` in my album page. It is a non-opencart page?

Comment: @PanktiShah Only via your own custom AJAX handler. Submit AJAX request on data change and store it on the server's session.

Comment: @PanktiShah before I posted an answeer I have tested it with OC and get session data outside OC in the same server. IT IS WORKING. Just before you will try to retrieve session data you should run the file which will save this data to the session.

Comment: @K.B. here I am trying to get session data from outside OC to OC.

Comment: @PanktiShah use the same vice versa. Do not forget to run your file using  JS or jquery first where you want to save session data. then retrieve it in OC and save for whole OC `$this->session->data['my_data'] = $_SESSION['my_data'];`

Comment: @K.B. I am not getting anything in ```$_SESSION['album']``` on my OC product page.